# Generating SVG pattern from the centre

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am creating a grid pattern (as per this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208673/how-to-draw-grid-using-html5-and-canvas-or-svg)) on the whole viewport.

The grid is generated from the top-left of the viewport, however, I want to generate it from the middle of the screen so that it consumes the whole screen yet is aligned from the centre. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `x` and `y` attributes of your SVG pattern. This website explains how you can various alignments for your SVG pattern:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/fill-patterns.html

Comment: Thanks for the link Osi. Unfortunately this doesnt work. Changing the X value will move it horizontally, however, when its generated, it wont consume the whole screen. So starting the grid pattern from the centre of the screen will leave the left side empty (without the grid). Do correct me if I am going wrong.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle example?

Comment: thanks a million. I had it wrong, it does fill the screen irrespective of where it begins. Here is the jsfiddle as requested. http://jsfiddle.net/RPDF4/14/ A few notes for making clear whats going on in the fiddle: the value in the #grid pattern is set to 300, i.e. 75% of viewbox. What this means, as per my understanding, is that the first grid line is being drawn from this point and all the others lines being drawn are with respect to this first line. Thanks again for the help Osi.