# Drawing a grid using SVG markup

Tags: svg, grid

I'm seeking to draw a grid onto which i will be adding a number of simple rectangles, again using SVG. The grid should fit on a single page when viewed in a browser. Suspect i'm missing something very simple but do i code the SVG (viewport and grid) for this outcome; namely a grid? 
I've read advice to specify a viewbox that defines the internal coordinate system of the document's canvas; also that it's possible to set height and width attributes as percentages (?). Ideally final result (ultimately a map) is to have gridlines.

Comment: Draw how?  Do you mean with javascript?  Is there a reason for that?  Why not just draw it up in an SVG editor like Inkscape (with snap to grid turned on etc).

Comment: The exercise also involves plotting a few points on the grid - requiring an SVG transform of these geographic objects (which are in a geographic coordinate system and not the opposite graphics coordinates system). These coordinates are all fed in from an Oracle spatial d/b.  So, it's more of a dynamic map that is the desired output, not a static one.

Comment: See this recent post, it may be helpful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915059/setting-background-image-to-dynamic-svg-data/21921872#21921872

Comment: Where is your code? Edit the question to add it.

Answer (score 16):

Use a [pattern](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#PatternElement) on a fully wide and high rectangle.

```html
<svg width="800" height="600">
<defs>
 <pattern id="tenthGrid" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="silver" stroke-width="0.5"/>
 </pattern>
 <pattern id="grid" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#tenthGrid)"/>
  <path d="M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="1"/>
 </pattern>
</defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)"/>
</svg>
```