# How to place SVG image file in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg

I have an SVG image file and I want to put it to in HTML page as an SVG. So I still take the advantage of Zoom in/out with high resolution.

Here is my code. I put the SVG inside the , the  inside the SVG.

The code run correctly but no SVG appear in the browser.

1. How can I show it?
2. Is there any way to place the SVG as SVG with all of its features( I read some question but non of them work with me).

```js
// this to draw the svg
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id="dsvg";
div.class="cdsvg";
div.style.width = "auto";
div.style.height = "210px";

var link='SVGimage.svg';

//creat svg to embed the svg to them
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svg.setAttribute("height", 210);
svg.setAttribute("width", 500);
//svg.setAttribute('xlink:href', link );

var XLink_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';

var img = document.createElementNS(svg, 'image');
img.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '210');
img.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '500');
img.setAttributeNS(XLink_NS, 'xlink:href', link);

svg.appendChild(img);

var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
div.appendChild(svg);
cell3.appendChild(div);
```

This HTML code is work but when I transfer it to JavaScript it does not ..

```
<svg id="svgimg" height="60" width="60" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  >
```

UPDATE:
I can see the SVG as img now:
I added the  library in order to change  to SVG( because I want to change the colour of the lines and rectangle inside the SVG )

```js
var link='test.svg';
var svgframe = document.createElement('img');
svgframe.id="svgframe";
svgframe.class="svg";
svgframe.setAttribute('src',link );

var SVGs = document.querySelectorAll('.svg');
SVGInjector(SVGs);
```

but when I see the inspect it is still img tag not SVG?? I want it as SVG so I can change the colour of the rectangles and the lines

Comment: I'm not sure to get the question but could this help: [SVG Injector](https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector)? It's really useful and efficient. It'll replace your <img> by a <svg>...</svg>.

Comment: hello @Cohars, It works with me when I put the image as HTML code .. but I want to use javascript since I want to show many images dynamically.

Comment: By "image" you mean <svg> code or <img src="***.svg"> because it's different. I don't really get what you want to do actually. Do you want to generate SVG code with JS or using existing .svg files?

Comment: >>> yes embedding sag as img will make the SVG lost the feature as I understod. yes I want to generate SVG code with JS or using existing .svg files>> because I want to add later on click to appear in new window + I can change the colour ..

Answer (score 2):

after our conversation in the comment, I think I can give you some help. Everything you need to know is [here, Iconic does a huge work](https://github.com/iconic/) on SVGs and opensource it.

Let's say you have icon.svg :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="8" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
  <path d="M2.47 0l-2.47 3h2v5h1v-5h2l-2.53-3z" transform="translate(1)" />
</svg>
```

You can add it in your html like that:

```
<img class="svg" data-src="icon.svg">
```

And you can use [SVG Injector](https://github.com/iconic/SVGInjector)

```
var IMGs = document.querySelectorAll('.svg');
SVGInjector(IMGs);
```

So you  will be replaced by the SVG code.
Than, you can style it

```
svg path {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: blue;
  fill: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help .. but  want to know how the change will be applied to the sag images since nothing change on the browser.. div.appendChild(SVGs); I tried to append the SVGs but I have this error :NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.

Comment: Well, SVG Injector is taking care of that, that's why I advice using it. It will basically make an AJAX request to get the SVG code of the file you write in `data-src`, then it will remove the <img> and replacing it by the SVG, and will keep the attributes (id, class etc). ou don't need to append it yourself to the DOM. Maybe you should make a JSFiddle to see what is your error.

Comment: I remove the append.. I put in the CSS : svg rect {fill: blue;}  && I add this in my code : var SVGs = document.querySelectorAll('svg'); SVGInjector(SVGs);.....>> bu the rectangles did not change at all!!

Comment: Ok, do you have any error in the console. What happen when you inspect the SVG, is it at the right size, does the CSS applies to `svg rect`, is css loaded? Maybe you can do `svg {width:100px; height:100px}`

Comment: No now I do not have error.. when I inspect the SVG nothing happened and the CSS did not applied to the SVG

Comment: But the SVG en the rect are present in your DOM. Is it highlighted when you inspect it? Does it have a size?

Comment: I think I don't have enough informations to help you efficiently.

Comment: yes the SVG image is present but I think as img not as SVG because nothing happened or changed on it

Comment: What is "sag"? You should be able to see if it's an <img> ta or a <svg> tag.

Comment: what do you mean that I should be able to see if it's an<img> ta or a <svg> tag.>> from where??

Comment: I tried to download the image and it is downloaded as SVG.. So the problem is how to chang its colour

Comment: From the console/element inspector of your browser. ([Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console))

Comment: from the inspector :<img id="svgframe" src="A_acidus_CBS_106_47_Aspfo1_0029042.svg" style="stroke: #ff0000;">  It is img may be thats why it does not change

Comment: Yes, it mean that your JS code does nothing. Are you sure that the SCG injector lib is loaded? I can't help you more than with the code I gave you above.

Comment: when you did yor code do you see the changes in the tags ?? <script src="svg-injector.min.js"></script> this is downloaded correctly since there is no error appear .. Thanks for the help and the time you giving me ..

Comment: Yes, the code supposed to work. I just made a mistake it `var IMGs = document.querySelectorAll('.svg');` with a `.` before svg as it is the class and not a tag.  Try to `console.log()` it to be sure to select it correctly.

Comment: <image x="0" y="0" height="60" width="60"  xlink:href="Aspfo1_0027407.svg" />

<script>
  var SVGs = document.querySelectorAll('.svg');
SVGInjector(SVGs);
</script>


I put this exactly as you said but from the inceptor it is still img tag

Comment: The img should have a data-src attributes. `<image data-src="Aspfo1_0027407.svg">`

Comment: BTW you have to insert [svg-inejctor.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iconic/SVGInjector/master/dist/svg-injector.min.js)

Comment: the image disappear when I put <image data-src="Aspfo1_0027407.svg">

when I put it src it appear again

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to. I'm sorry but I can't keep "chatting" with you like that in the comments. Please add more details to your question (like your SVG code, HTML, JS, CSS)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to dynamically create your SVG element and then have it display in the browser.

Here's a rough cut of how I've done it in the past. This solution uses jQuery's [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function:

```
    var svgdiv = document.createElement('div');
    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('height', heightVar);
    svg.setAttribute('width', widthVar);
    //Add all your elements to the SVG
    svgdiv.appendChild(svg)
    //the following shows it in a pop-up window, but the write() and html() functions should be what you need.
    window.open().document.write(svgdiv.html());
```

More precisely, if you wanted to place the SVG at a specific point in the document, such as the div `myDiv`:

`$('#myDiv').html(svgdiv.html());`

Comment: thanks but where can I put the source of the image that I have (var link='SVGimage.svg';)  !! SVG element does not have this attribute !!

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect

```
var img = document.createElementNS(svg, 'image');
```

You have the namespace right for the svg element

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
```

so you just need to do the same again for the image i.e.

```
var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
```

Comment: but the question can I deal with it later as SVG image >> can I change the colour of the lines inside the image if I embed it in this way ??

Comment: If you mean in the SVG itself yes (the SVG or the image tag attributes), if you mean the data in the SVG's image tag, i.e. the contents of SVGImage.svg then the answer is no.

Comment: the SVG image contains many lines and rectangles ) yes I want to change the colour of them later ( change all the rectangle colours).. I understood from answer that I cane do this ????

Answer (score 0):

- Use parameters:
  http://localhost/circle.svg?color=blue
- Use inline CSS:

  ```
  var s="url(\"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%'><defs><pattern id='grid' width='"+(37+i)+".79527559055' height='37.79527559055' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse' style='&#10;'><path d='M 50 0 L 0 0 0 40' fill='none' stroke='gray' stroke-width='1'/></pattern></defs><rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='url(#grid)'/></svg>\") no-repeat";  
  document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0].style.background=s;
  ```

  Somebody also mentioned this but using with encodeURI... 
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42313650/1347572